# Understanding And Getting info of Bitmap in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I am having a hard time understanding and parsing the info data present in a bitmap image. To better understand I read the following tutorial, [Raster Data.](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/raster.html)

Now, The code present there is as follows, (Greyscale 8bit color value)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*-------STRUCTURES---------*/
typedef struct {int rows; int cols; unsigned char* data;} sImage;

/*-------PROTOTYPES---------*/
long getImageInfo(FILE*, long, int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE          *bmpInput, *rasterOutput;
  sImage        originalImage;
  unsigned char     someChar;
  unsigned char*    pChar;
  int           nColors;  /* BMP number of colors */
  long          fileSize; /* BMP file size */
  int           vectorSize; /* BMP vector size */
  int           r, c;       /* r = rows, c = cols */


  /* initialize pointer */
  someChar = '0';
  pChar = &someChar;

  if(argc < 2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s bmpInput.bmp\n", argv[0]);
    //end the execution
    exit(0);
  }
  printf("Reading filename %s\n", argv[1]);

  /*--------READ INPUT FILE------------*/
  bmpInput = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
  //fseek(bmpInput, 0L, SEEK_END);

  /*--------DECLARE OUTPUT TEXT FILE--------*/
  rasterOutput = fopen("data.txt", "w");

  /*--------GET BMP DATA---------------*/
  originalImage.cols = (int)getImageInfo(bmpInput, 18, 4);
  originalImage.rows = (int)getImageInfo(bmpInput, 22, 4);
  fileSize = getImageInfo(bmpInput, 2, 4);
  nColors = getImageInfo(bmpInput, 46, 4);
  vectorSize = fileSize - (14 + 40 + 4*nColors);

  /*-------PRINT DATA TO SCREEN-------------*/
  printf("Width: %d\n", originalImage.cols);
  printf("Height: %d\n", originalImage.rows);
  printf("File size: %ld\n", fileSize);
  printf("# Colors: %d\n", nColors);
  printf("Vector size: %d\n", vectorSize);

  /*----START AT BEGINNING OF RASTER DATA-----*/
  fseek(bmpInput, (54 + 4*nColors), SEEK_SET);

  /*----------READ RASTER DATA----------*/
  for(r=0; r<=originalImage.rows - 1; r++)
  {
    for(c=0; c<=originalImage.cols - 1; c++)
    {
      /*-----read data and print in (row,column) form----*/
      fread(pChar, sizeof(char), 1, bmpInput);
      fprintf(rasterOutput, "(%d, %d) = %d\n", r, c, *pChar);
    }
  }

  fclose(bmpInput);
  fclose(rasterOutput);


}


/*----------GET IMAGE INFO SUBPROGRAM--------------*/
long getImageInfo(FILE* inputFile, long offset, int numberOfChars)
{
  unsigned char     *ptrC;
  long          value = 0L;
  unsigned char     dummy;
  int           i;

  dummy = '0';
  ptrC = &dummy;

  fseek(inputFile, offset, SEEK_SET);

  for(i=1; i<=numberOfChars; i++)
  {
    fread(ptrC, sizeof(char), 1, inputFile);
    /* calculate value based on adding bytes */
    value = (long)(value + (*ptrC)*(pow(256, (i-1))));
  }
  return(value);

} /* end of getImageInfo */
```

**What I am not understanding:-**

1. I am unable the understand the **'GET IMAGE INTOSUBPROGRAM'** part where the code is trying to get the image infos like no of rows,columns, etc. Why are these infos stored over 4 bytes and what is the use of the  `value = (long)(value + (*ptrC)*(pow(256, (i-1))));` instruction.
2. Why there  `unsigned char dummy ='0'` is created and then  `ptrC =&dummy` is assigned?
3. Why can't we just get the no of rows in an image by just reading 1 byte of data like getting the Greyscale value at a particular row and column.
4. Why are we using **unsigned char** to store the byte, isn't there some other data type or int or long we can use effectively here?

Please help me understand these doubts(confusions!!?) I am having and forgive me if they sound noobish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the tutorial is quite bad in some ways and your problems to understand it are not always due to being a beginner.

> I am unable the understand the 'GET IMAGE INTOSUBPROGRAM' part where the code is trying to get the image infos like no of rows,columns, etc. Why are these infos stored over 4 bytes and what is the use of the value = (long)(value + (*ptrC)*(pow(256, (i-1)))); instruction.

The reason to store over 4 bytes is to allow the image to be sized between 0 and 2^32-1 high and wide. If we used just one byte, we could only have images sized 0..255 and with 2 bytes 0..65535.

The strange `value = (long)(value + (*ptrC)*(pow(256, (i-1))));` is something I've never seen before. It's used to convert bytes into a long so that it would work with any endianness. The idea is to use powers of 256 to set the `*ptrC` to the `value`, i.e. multiplying first byte with 1, next with 256, next with 65536 etc.

A much more readable way would be to use shifts, e.g. `value = value + ((long)(*ptrC) << 8*(i-1));`. Or even better would be to read bytes from the highest one to lower and use `value = value << 8 + *ptrC;`. In my eyes a lot better, but when the bytes come in a different order, is not always so simple.

A simple rewrite to be much easier to understand would be

```
long getImageInfo(FILE* inputFile, long offset, int numberOfChars)
{
  unsigned char     ptrC;
  long          value = 0L;
  int           i;

  fseek(inputFile, offset, SEEK_SET);

  for(i=0; i<numberOfChars; i++)  // Start with zero to make the code simpler
  {
    fread(&ptrC, 1, 1, inputFile); // sizeof(char) is always 1, no need to use it
    value = value + ((long)ptrC << 8*i); // Shifts are a lot simpler to look at and understand what's the meaning
  }
  return value; // Parentheses would make it look like a function
}
```

> Why there unsigned char dummy ='0' is created and then ptrC =&dummy is assigned?

This is also pointless. They could've just used `unsigned char ptrC` and then used `&ptrC` instead of `ptrC` and `ptrC` instead of `*ptrC`. This would've also shown that it is just a normal static variable.

> Why can't we just get the no of rows in an image by just reading 1 byte of data like getting the Greyscale value at a particular row and column.

What if the image is 3475 rows high? One byte isn't enough. So it needs more bytes. The way of reading is just a bit complicated.

> Why are we using unsigned char to store the byte, isn't there some other data type or int or long we can use effectively here?

Unsigned char is exactly one byte long. Why would we use any other type for storing a byte then?

Answer (score 1):

(4) The data of binary files is made up of bytes, which in C are represented by `unsigned char`. Because that's a long word to type, it is sometimes `typedef`fed to `byte` or `uchar`. A good standard-compliant way to define bytes is to use `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

(3) I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get at, but the first bytes - usually 54, but there are othzer BMF formats - of a BMP file make up the header, which contains information on colour depth, width and height of an image. The bytes after byte 54 store the raw data. I haven't tested yopur code, but there might be an issue with padding, because the data for each row must be padded to make a raw-data size that is divisible by 4.

(2) There isn't really a point in defining an extra pointer here. You could just as well `fread(&dummy, ...)` directly.

(1) Ugh. This function reads a multi-byte value from the file at position `offset` in the file. The file is made up of bytes, but several bytes can form other data types. For example, a 4-byte unsigned word is made up of:

```
uint8_t raw[4];
uint32_t x;

x = raw[0] + raw[1]*256 + raw[2]*256*256 + raw[3]*256*256*256;
```

on a PC, which uses Little Endian data.

That example also shows where the `pow(256, i)` comes in. Using the `pow` function here is not a good idea, because it is meant to be used with floating-point numbers. Even the multiplication by 256 is not very idiomatic. Usually, we construct values by byte shifting, where a multiplication by 2 is a left-shift by 1 and hence a multiplication by 256 is a left-shift by 8. Similarly, the additions above add non-overlapping ranges and are usually represented as a bitwise OR, `|`:

```
x = raw[0] | (raw[1]<<8) | (raw[2]<<16) | (raw[3]<<24);
```

The function accesses the file by re-positioning the file pointer (and leaving it at the new position). That's not very effective. It would be better to read the header as an 54-byte array and accessing the array directly.

The code is old and clumsy. Seeing something like:

```
for(r=0; r<=originalImage.rows - 1; r++)
```

is already enough for me not to trust it. I'm sure you can find a better example of reading greyscale images from BMP. You could even write your own and start with the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) on the BMP format.